# 4runner wont shift out of first gear on an automatic

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, 4runner

If i've takin the ABS out of my 2000 4runner will it cause to not shift? What I did was take a 2000 4runner sr5 4 wheel drive and took the four by transmission out and put a 2 wheel drive transmission in and made it 2 wheel drive and now when I put it in gear no matter D,2,1 it will only stay in first gear. I have park, reverse and first gear only. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the transmission electronically controlled? If so, there may not be a command for the transmission to shift from first to 2nd to 3rd and so forth.

Comment: I assume you connected the electrical plugs all as they were before?

Comment: I got it fixed. The speed sensor was bad and not allowing it to shift.